# Optimized parsing(extracting) json data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

im sending http request (using ajax) to my sever, and it returns json string something like :

```
{

    "neighbors":{
        "data":[
            {
                "id":"7f40cb24-603e-4943-9a0b-e16e024c8bd5",
                "name":"jeff ferry",
                "picture":"url",
                "location":{
                    "data":[
                        {
                            "latitude":"xxx",
                            "longitude":"yyy"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and in html page ajax callback im accessing data like :

```
success: function (data) {

    var outerObj = data.neighbor.data;    
    var res = ""; 

    for (i in outerObj )          
    {
    if (outerObj .hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // my outer stuff              
            var innerObj = outerObj.data;
            for (j in innerObj)          
            {
            // my inner stuff
                if (innerObj.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                }
            }
        }                                            
    }
}
```

but im wondering if i can access it by some optimized(shorter) way ?

any help appreciable

Comment: Why do you call regular accessing the object elements "parsing"?

Comment: If `longitude` / `latitude` are the only 2 sup-properties per `neighbour`, you can just check for those and obtain them.
Other than that, there's not really a shorter way.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: i access that all elements and render it as a html

Comment: Which part of the data would that be? And how would the expected HTML look like. If you **do** want this question answered, do fill in with the details.

Comment: Btw: To match the JSON string, data.neighbor.data should be data.neighbors.data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could tighten up the data structure returned from the server? Since 1) the location property is really just a lat/long tuple, and 2) the object around the inner `data` array is just a redundant wrapper, how about this:

```
{
    "neighbors":[
        {
            "id":"7f40cb24-603e-4943-9a0b-e16e024c8bd5",
            "name":"jeff ferry",
            "picture":"url",
            "location":["xxx","yyy"]
        }
    ]
}
```

That way, your JavaScript becomes something like:

```
success: function (data) {

    var res = ""; // what was this for, anyway?

    for (var n in data.neighbors) if (data.neighbors.hasOwnProperty(n) {
        var neighbor = data.neighbors[n];
        // actions on the neighbor object here

        var location = neighbor.location;
        // actions on the location here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use jQuery

```
var data
$.getJSON(thejsonfile, function(e) {
   data = e.neighbors.data[0]
})
```

now all the data inside "neighbors" is in data and you can refer to them using "data"

so like  to get id refer to it this way `var id  = data.id`

NOTE: anything in these square brackets `[]` refer to a loop which if there was one or more data inside the "neighbors" list you'd have to loop using `$.map() or $.each()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only care about the inner properties, I would just wrap it in a try-catch block.

```
var outer, inner;
try {
    outer = data.neighbors.data[0];
    inner = outer.location.data[0];
    delete outer.location;
} catch (e) {
    // no good
}
```

Ie, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/4szft/1).

**Outer**

> {"id":"7f40cb24-603e-4943-9a0b-e16e024c8bd5","name":"jeff ferry","picture":"url"}

**Inner**

> {"latitude":"xxx","longitude":"yyy"}

Answer (score 1):

`neighbours.data` is an array. If you wish to iterate through them, you a for loop as opposed to a foreach.

```
var i = 0,
    outerLength = (neighbours.data && neighbours.data.length) || 0,
    innerLength, j,
    outerObj, innerObj;

for (; i < length; i++) {
    outerObj = neighbours.data[i];

    j = 0;
    innerLength = (outerObj.data && outerObj.data.length) || 0;

    for (; j < innerLength; j++) {

        innerObj = outerObj.data[j];
        // do what you wish! 
    }

}
```